# ORA-01722: invalid number with RPAD

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a case where I want to take the date of birth and pad it with eight ' ' empty spaces

This is what I have

```
CASE
    WHEN Date_of_Birth IS NULL THEN rpad(' ', 8, ' ')
    ELSE substr(
      (replace(
        to_char(to_date(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
        '/',
        ''
      ) + rpad(' ',(length(' ') * 8),' '))
      ,1,8
    )
END Date_of_Birth_1,
```

The DATE_OF_BIRTH is NVARCHAR2. I'm getting the error saying that RPAD is an invalid number,

I figured changing the date to a to_char would change it to a string then to add the spaces at the end of it.

Comment: _"DATE_OF_BIRTH is NVARCHAR2"_ Why not `Date`?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve with `+ rpad(...)` (apart from replacement of `+` with `||`) because `mm/dd/yyyy` with replaced slashes will have exactly eight symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to convert the string `DATE_OF_BIRTH` column from `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format to `MMDDYYYY` format and if it is `NULL` then provide 8 spaces.

That can be achieved without the complicated use of string functions using:

```sql
COALESCE(
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MMDDYYYY'),
  '        '
) AS Date_of_Birth_1,
```

*Note: there is no need to replace the `/` separators in a date or to remove trailing spaces if you never include them in the first palce.*

Answer (score 0):

by the + sign, did you mean to concatenate strings like in Javascript?  String concatenation in Oracle uses ||

Aside from that, you should also check to make sure date_of_birth is in fact in the YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS format in your data or you can get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is the concatenation operator (as Paul already said).

Though, you could simplify that code.

- `date_of_birth` is the original value, stored in the table
- `date_of_birth_1` is result based on your code
- `date_of_birth_2` is result on my (simplified) code

---

```
SQL> set null 'null'
SQL> select
  2  id,
  3  date_of_birth,
  4  --
  5  CASE WHEN Date_of_Birth IS NULL THEN
  6          rpad(' ', 8, ' ')
  7       ELSE substr( (replace( to_char(to_date(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '/', '' ) || rpad(' ',(length(' ') * 8),' ')) ,1,8 )
  8  END Date_of_Birth_1,
  9  --
 10  case when date_of_birth is null then '        '
 11       else to_char(to_date(date_of_birth, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mmddyyyy')
 12  end date_of_birth_2
 13  from test;

        ID DATE_OF_BIRTH        DATE_OF_BIRTH_1      DATE_OF_BIRTH_2
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 2020-08-25 13:20:28  08252020             08252020
         2 2015-03-18           03182015             03182015
         3 null

SQL>
```